# Is This Operator Override Valid

Tags: c#, overriding

I am trying to create a simple class that represents a Report File. I wish to append strings to the report file (the strings will be stored in the class but not written upon each append). Is it valid to override the `+` operator so that it takes a string as a parameter and returns a `Report` object?

For example;

```
    // Is this valid code? If not how can I achieve this?
    public Report operator + (string text)
    {
        fileContents.Append(text);
    }
```

Currently this method gives the compiler error:

> The parameter of a unary operator must be the containing type

Intended usage:

```
Report r = new Report("myUniqueReport");
r += "Some line of text";
.. peform unrelated logic

r.write();
```

Complete class:

```
class Report
{
    protected StringBuilder fileContents = new StringBuilder();

    public Report(string reportName)
    {
        // TODO: create file in current project dir or desktop with reportName but must be unique name
    }

    // Is this valid code?
    public Report operator + (string text)
    {
        fileContents.Append(text);
    }

    public void write() 
    {
        // todo write string builder to file
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it valid? Did you try compiling it?

Comment: You are overloading unary `+` (like in `int v = +1;`) instead of binary `+`.

Answer (score 3):

I would not recommend to use operator overloading in this case.

While technically speaking, the operator may look like this:

```
public static Report operator + (Report report, string text)
{
    report.fileContents.Append(text);
    return report;
}
```

[but](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691324%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

> While it is possible for a user-defined operator to perform any computation it pleases, implementations that produce results other than those that are intuitively expected are strongly discouraged

Please note that the operator is also **confusing**:

```
 Report report1 = report + "string";
```

will change the state of `report`. And if we want to prevent it, we'd need to create a new Report copy `StringBuilder` every time we use overloaded operator `+`.